# MSSQL - No Result or NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a little problem.

I'm SELECTING From a table. I want to see a value what is just used only in one point of my workflow. Before that no value here.

But, if no result, then my "result" is `NULL`.  And thats not good for me.

I mean, if I write

```
SELECT myValue FROM myTable WHERE asd = 'thisIs'
```

when `myValue` is `NULL` in the table, then my result is `NULL`. Thats okay.
when no results found, then my result is `NULL` too. Thats not okay.

If no result I have do different function.
How can I separate these ?

```
   |MyValue|
---|-------|
 1 |NULL   |
---|-------|


   |MyValue|
---|-------|


   |MyValue|
---|-------|
 1 |Hello  |
---|-------|
```

In the first and third case I have to call an Update function, in the second case I have to call an Insert function.

But the result what my SP is sending back in the first and second case is NULL too.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: You need to post code or it's impossible to help you.

Comment: use `IF EXISTS` then you do what you want `ELSE` some different function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you want to do something like this:

```
IF EXISTS (
SELECT myValue FROM myTable WHERE asd = 'thisIs'
) 
BEGIN
    SELECT myValue FROM myTable WHERE asd = 'thisIs'
END
ELSE 
BEGIN
    EXEC SomeOtherCode
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can count number of rows found after select records query. if count is greater or equal to one you have to run update query else insert query as selected records are empty.